# DNS does not Resolve via Internal Domain Controller

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-controller, internal-dns, amazon-route53, dns-hosting

When I want to create a new DNS name e.g. `foo.example.com`, I add it to Amazon AWS's Route 53, so it becomes available on the internet.

However, when navigating to the address from inside my companies network, the web browsers are unable to resolve the DNS address.

So I have to also add the DNS name to the domain controllers register of DNS names. Once we do this, we can also then use the address from inside our network.

Why do I have to do this and is it possible to get around this, so we don't have to enter DNS names in two places?

Comment: Have you given the registry the new NS records pointing to AWS nameservers?

Comment: @TorinCarey Which registry are you talking about? DNS only seems to work on my internal network when I add the DNS record to the domain controller.

Comment: You need to give the new nameservers to your domain registrar. If you're comfortable posting the domain, it would be easy to see what's going on.